# Remove color from parts of a plot in R

Tags: r, colors, transparency

I am looking for a way to remove the color from parts of a plot. E.g. I draw a black rectangle and then I want to draw another one overlapping with it with "no color". In the final pdf I don't want it to be white but transparent.

```
pdf()
plot(9,9)
rect(7,7,10,10,col="black")
rect(8,8,9,9,col="white") #not white!
dev.off()
```

Later I want to do this with a cylindersegment, but this is a simpler example.

Comment: I don't really understand the request, but did you read `?rect`, particularly the section related to the `col` argument?

Comment: Yes, I did. The default is NULL, which means transparent, which means the black rectangle will shine through. But I don't want the black rectangle to be visible there. If you look at my image with `display` (linux), then you will see, that the background of a plot is not white but transparent, but the second smaller rectangle will be white and not transparent.

Comment: Still hard to understand. You want the white rectangle to erase the black one? What you are asking is not possible with `rect` then. You need a polygon as suggested by @Thomas.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Because it will be much easier due to many overlapping objects, I will use `convert` with `-transparent white` after I create the image. This will change all white parts to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing a polygon instead:

```
pdf("example.pdf")
plot(NA, xlim = c(0,15), ylim = c(0,15))
polygon(c(8,8,9,9,8,7,10,10,7,7), 
        c(8,9,9,8,8,7,7,10,10,7), col="black")
dev.off()
```

Comment: It won't be that simple in the end. The "colorless" segments (cylinders) will overlap with multiple rectangles.

Comment: @Godrebh Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying.